# Will Windows Update find chipset drivers?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, windows-update, chipset

Does Windows Update in Windows 7 find and install chipset drivers? It will automatically find newer versions of video and audio drivers, etc., but will it do the same for chipset updates?

Answer (score 2):

There's no specific rule or policy that would exclude chipset drivers from Windows Update (at least not that I'm aware of). It's up to each manufacturer to submit their drivers to Microsoft, who will then make those drivers available through Windows Update (provided they pass the [WHQL testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WHQL_Testing), of course).

To check whether Windows Update has a specific driver available (whether for a chipset or any other piece of hardware), you can search [Microsoft Update Catalog](http://catalog.update.microsoft.com).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you use Action Center in Windows 7 it can search and find the all of drivers. you can choose your newest driver, download and install it into your computer automatically.Best way is use the windows update for find and download newest divers.

Comment: I have never seen a chipset update offered using Windows update, ever.